# using web view in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

this might sound silly but since i am new to iPhone i wanted to ask this question... :P 
Where is the UIWebView best used? I mean which type of application?
Could i use that if i wanted to display a video in some part of the screen rather than fullscreen which MPmediaPlayer is really good at?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only places I have seen UIWebView really used in a way that is right is for help pages.  Developers will make this page call a FAQ page hosted on their servers so that they can change the contents frequently without going back to Apple for review.

Comment: thanks!...that clears some of my doubts regarding UIWebView... :)